# Find all tokens issues for a specified user by username

Tags: java, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

How can I find all the tokens issued for a user to all clients by username?

Currently, `org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.TokenStore` provides only one API method that allows token search by `username`, which is `findTokensByClientIdAndUserName`.

To search for all the tokens issued to **all** clients, one needs to iterate over a list of known clients.

Is there a better way of getting all the tokens by username?

UPDATE: In my case I am using `RedisTokenStore`.

Comment: Looks like `RedisTokenStore` doesn't have it, e.g. like [`JdbcTokenStore`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/oauth/apidocs/org/springframework/security/oauth2/provider/token/store/JdbcTokenStore.html#findTokensByUserName(java.lang.String)). If you need it badly enough, you can extend `RedisTokenStore` and add the method yourself. The source code for the latest `RedisTokenStore` can be found [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/blob/master/spring-security-oauth2/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/oauth2/provider/token/store/redis/RedisTokenStore.java).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A generic solution that works for every implementation of `TokenStore` is to use `TokenStore#findTokensByClientIdAndUserName` for every registered client.

If you use an implementation of `ClientRegistrationService`, then you can utilize `ClientRegistrationService#listClientDetails` to iterate over a list of clients and find tokens issued to each of them:

```
for (ClientDetails client : clientRegistrationService.listClientDetails()) {
    for (final OAuth2AccessToken token : tokenStore.findTokensByClientIdAndUserName(clientId, email)) {
        tokenStore.removeRefreshToken(token.getRefreshToken());
        tokenStore.removeAccessToken(token);
    }
}
```

If you don't use `ClientRegistrationService`, then you need to maintain a list of `clientIds` yourself.

The only implementation of `TokenStore` in `spring-security-oauth2` that has `findTokensByUserName` is `JdbcTokenStore`.